# How to find a point with longitude and latitude in a Highmaps maps serie, initiated with GeoJson?

Tags: highcharts, geolocation, geojson, highmaps

I do have a simple highmaps map based on this example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.x/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/de/de-all-all

I would like to update a specific point, based on a latitude and a longitude. How can I achieve this?

To update a specific point value, I can do:

```
$('#container').highcharts().series[0].points[pointId].update(value);
```

But how can I find the pointId based on a longitude and a latitude?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not avaible yet, so at this moment we use number coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The first map without geo coordinates support!

Really sad